# Pushing saved user outside Modal in angular ui bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular-bootstrap

I have a list of users and an 'Add User' button that opens a modal lightbox popup using Angular  bootstrap. I can save the user and update the list if it's all on the same page (without opening the pop up). I can save the user and NOT update the list if I use the pop up (I have to refresh the page to see changes to the list).

Here's my save function

```
 $scope.add = function() {
        if (!$scope.users) $scope.users = [];

        var user = new Users({
            email: $scope.user.email,
            company: $scope.user.company,
            store: $scope.user.store,
            section: $scope.user.section,
            phone: $scope.user.phone,
            name: $scope.user.name,
            username: $scope.user.username,
            password: $scope.user.password,
            confirmPassword: $scope.user.confirmPassword,
            roles: $scope.user.roles
        });

        user.$save(function(response) {
            $scope.users.push(response);
        });

        this.firstName = this.lastName = this.email = this.password = this.role = '';
    };
```

And here's my OK button

```
      $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();

       };
```

The OK will close the dialog, but I need to $scope.users.push(response); to the list OUTSIDE this controller. There's an example of changing variables, but I'm unfamiliar with invoking a push command within the close command.

I'm trying something like

```
        // This will save the user & close the pop up but the list of users doesn't refresh/show changes.
        user.$save(function(response) {
          $modalInstance.close($scope.users.push(response));
        });
```